# How to print div on each page using jsPrintSetup addon

Tags: javascript, printing, mozilla

I want to repeat particular div on each page.I have tried css by doing position:fixed in media query,But it creates design issue so i do not want to use it.Can anyone please suggest me any method of jsprintsetup(mozilla addon) so that i can accomplish this task easily.